# manually updating validity of the elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I'm using `jquery.validate` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` and I wonder how can I manually make certain elements "valid" or "invalid" from the javascript code?

I'm trying to modify `$('form').validate()` properties like `successList` `invalid` and `errorMap` but it still doesn't change `$('form').valid()`'s behavior, so apparently I'm not doing that right.

Comment: Why would you want to over-ride what you've previously instructed the plugin to do for you?

Comment: let's say your input field needs a custom validation and depends on other element's value e.g. dropdown

Comment: If that's the case, then that's not what you originally asked for.  You asked how to _"manually make certain elements valid or invalid"_, which makes no sense.  If you simply want a custom rule or method, then you would use the `addMethod()` method to turn your custom function into a new rule.

Comment: See my edited answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> "I wonder how can I manually make certain elements "valid" or "invalid"
>   from the javascript code?"

Only the assigned `rules` along with the user-entered data can "*make*" an input element `valid` or `invalid`.   There is no method for you to over-ride this, otherwise there's really no point in using the plugin.

---

However, you can *dynamically* change any of the rules using the [`.rules('add')` and `.rules('remove')` methods](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules).

---

**EDIT based on OP's comment:**

> let's say your input field needs a custom validation and depends on
>   other element's value e.g. dropdown

Use the [built-in method called `addMethod`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage) to turn your custom function into a custom rule for the plugin to use.